# Java11 / JavaFX and Maven will not run outside of NetBeans IDE 9

Tags: maven, javafx, java-11, netbeans-9

As per [JavaFX deployment library not found in active JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51987518/javafx-deployment-library-not-found-in-active-jdk/52138742#52138742)

I used  José Pereda  Maven approach and it works well in NetBeans but as soon as I try and run it outside with "java -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar" I get the following error 
"Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application" 
 The "md.mavenproject1.MainApp" is just a temp name while I try and figure this out.
My pom file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>md</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass>md.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <!-- Used as the 'Vendor' for JNLP generation -->
        <name>Your Organisation</name>
    </organization>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11-ea+25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.1</version>
                        <!--  Use newer version of ASM  -->
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>md.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>md.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> 
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And my nbactions.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<actions>
        <action>
            <actionName>run</actionName>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>package</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <runfx.args>-jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
            </properties>
        </action>
        <action>
            <actionName>debug</actionName>
            <goals>
                <goal>clean</goal>
                <goal>package</goal>
                <goal>org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java</goal>
            </goals>
            <properties>
                <runfx.args>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=${jpda.address} -Dglass.disableGrab=true -jar "${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.jar"</runfx.args>
                <jpda.listen>true</jpda.listen>
            </properties>
        </action>        
    </actions>
```

Any help you can give me will be of great help as I am thinking of switching my highschool programming kids from ant to maven with the change in JavaFX but they will want to be able to take there programs home to use. I am running OpenJDK 11 on my system.

**edit **
I changed the line to run the program to:

```
java --module-path c:\javafx-sdk-11\lib --add-modules javafx.controls -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

and now I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x11a24f71) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x11a24f71
        at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
        at md.test33.MainApp.start(MainApp.java:15)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application md.mavenproject1.MainApp
```

I though with using maven's dependencies that I wouldn't need to use the local jdk.  Any help anyone could give would be really helpful.  If I take out the dependencies and use Oracle java 10 jdk the program and run outside of netbeans but with java 11 it only runs inside. Please help.

## ** EDIT **

By editing the pom file and removing:

```
 <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>md.mavenproject1.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and instead using:

```
  <!--  Used to make dependencys needed to run the program -->  
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- makes the JAR file to run the program outside -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>           
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I was now able to change the start up line to use the attached JavaFX lib that I added instead of having to use the SDK that I downloaded.

```
java --module-path lib --add-modules javafx.controls --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.beans=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I would like to make it include the jre instead of using the local one.  If anyone has any idea how it would be great.

Comment: On a side note, the [maven-compiler-plugin can be updated and simplified.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51586202/1746118)

Comment: OK, I got that updated as well. Shouldn't I be able to use the javaFX modules that I included in the jar instead of having to use the ones I downloaded to javafx-sdk-11?

Comment: The last I remember the modules didn't have a proper automatic module name generated [something like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9). So using them instead of SDK was something I failed at with the module system. Honestly, I haven't given a try [since then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51843208/running-javafx-sample-on-jdk-11-with-openjfx-11-jmods-on-module-path).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way to fix that would be to append the following args to the command line

```
--add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  I had to change the command to:  java --module-path c:\javafx-sdk-11\lib --add-modules javafx.controls --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.beans=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.utils=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk=ALL-UNNAMED -jar mavenproject1-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.  Everytime I fixxed one another came up until I end up with that.

Comment: @MathewDusome This was very helpful! What do you think is a more permanent fix for this? (I'm new to Java/JavaFx/Eclipse, sorry)

Comment: As a permanent fix, I added a module-info.java file with what I needed.module md { 
requires javafx.fxml; 
requires javafx.controls; 
requires javafx.graphics; 
requires javafx.base; 
requires javafx.media; 
opens md.mavenproject1; 
}

Answer (score 0):

I've got similar issue when doing default hello world javafx project in the IntelliJ IDEA with openjdk 11 and openjfx 11. The work around is to use offered CLI in the project configuration.

[image]

But in this case the solution is kind of hack instead of proper configuration fix.
My problem was that I hadn't any `module-info.java` to initialize proper java platform module. Therefore the IntelliJ module is actually *unnamed module*. After create proper module descriptor the project is not unnamed platform module any more.

Next issue what I got is related to using external java platform module as a jar file (openjfx libs to be specific). This need to be solved by adding *libraries* in the project structure settings.

[image]

And then it will work without any additional CLI arguments.