# Why cannot run compiled JavaFX 11 from OpenJDK

Tags: java, javafx

Following instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx, I compiled the sample HelloFX.java via:

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX.java
```

I got error:

> error: module not found: javafx.controls
>   1 error

then I add the line as instructs:
    javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add modules=javafx.controls.javafx.fxml HelloFX.java

and got error:

> error: module not found: javafx.fxml
>   error: module not found: javafx.controls
>   2 errors

then I add the last line in the instructions:
    java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules=javafx.controls HelloFX

and got error:

> Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
>   java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found

Please help!

Comment: Please edit it and make it more readable.

Comment: `$PATH_TO_FX` is a variable meant to either be set by you or replaced with the actual path to the JavaFX SDK. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes I did. It still created the same errors that I mentioned above

Comment: I believe the SDK is downloaded as a ZIP file, at least for Windows. Did you extract the contents and then point to the `lib` directory?

Comment: The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673450/269514

Answer (score 0):

I had to also include the 'lib' directory:  `--module-path %PATH_TO_FX%;%PATH_TO_FX%\lib`  to make it compile. (Windows 10)