# Why isn't my JavaFX application showing a web browser?

Tags: java, macos, javafx, jpackage

I have a modular JavaFX application with the following Java code:

```
package webbrowser;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebBrowser extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.oracle.com");
        Scene scene = new Scene(browser, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Here is the module-info.java file:

```
module webBrowser {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.web;
    
    exports webbrowser;
}
```

I compile the modular JavaFX application with the following command:

```
javac -d out --module-source-path . --module-path $JAVAFX_SDK/libs:$JAVAFX_JMODS --module webBrowser
```

I package the modular JavaFX application with the following command:

```
jpackage --type dmg --module-path $JAVAFX_JMODS:$JAVAFX_SDK/lib:out --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.web,javafx.graphics,javafx.media --module webBrowser/webbrowser.WebBrowser
```

Then I save the application in my /Applications folder (I'm on Mac OS) and open the application. The application opens a 500x500 window, but it doesn't render any graphics, and it doesn't open a web browser. The application just opens a white blank 500x500 window.

Why isn't the application running properly?

When I run the application with java (and forego jpackage) the application runs fine in the JVM, opens a web browser, and opens the oracle.com webpage.

```
java --module-path out:$JAVAFX_JMODS:$JAVAFX_SDK/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.web --module webBrowser/webbrowser.WebBrowser
```

Why doesn't the application work when I use jpackage, install the dmg and run the Mac OS app?

Comment: Which version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: Use only the jmods dir for jpackage/jlink, and only lib folder for java/javac. Don't forget to try `--win-console`, see info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456027/java-fx-application-with-jpackage-not-work/70460422#70460422)

Answer (score 2):

The section of the openjfx.io documentation on [runtime images, modular from CLI](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular), demonstrates some of the points outlined below and provides examples of the command line arguments to use for compiling, linking, packaging and executing the application.

I suggest you get the linked openjfx demo working in your environment, then try the same for your project.

Some issues to address:

1. jmods can't be used at runtime, only at compile or link time.

   - e.g. don't pass the jmods to the java command.
   - For more info, see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39086501/1155209) to:

     - [Add a custom JMOD to the module path with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38267059/add-a-custom-jmod-to-the-module-path-with-java-9/39086501#39086501)
2. `--add-modules` is not required for java/javac when you have a module-info.java.

   - for jpackage just list your app module in `--add-modules`, you don't need to list the javafx package because it can work that out from your module-info.
3. Your lib directory is inconsistent, always use the same (correct) directory:

   - sometimes you use `lib` and sometimes you use `libs`.
4. Provide an [onError](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#onErrorProperty) handler.
5. When using jpackage you should have only the JavaFX mods.

   - you don't need the mods and SDK lib, use only mods.

Further points to check are highlighted in the answer to:

- [Java FX Application with Jpackage not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70456027/java-fx-application-with-jpackage-not-work)